# Relative pronoun like objects introduced without a comma...?

Tags: grammar-identification

> Die Folge der Erderwärmung in seiner dramatischsten Form ist die Ausdehnung **der** auf der Erde verteilten Ozeane.

Could someone explain how the "der" works in the above? It feels like a relative pronommen, but normally those are introduced with a comma.

Comment: "der" must be a plural for "Ozeane", because if it were a relative pronoun, you would have a conjugated verb in the end, plus the ending "-en" of "verteilten" would not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "der" is just the article of "Ozeane" (genitive, plural) and "auf der Erde verteilten" is again one of those participial constructions that tend to confuse you.

Comment: Could you explain how you deduce that?

Comment: @trystwithfreedom, this is a grammatical way to parse the sentence, so as long as there isn’t another one it must be what is meant, right?

Comment: Does the sentence mean "The most dramatic consequence of global warming is the rise in the Earth's sea level"? Also, what does the "verteilten" mean? None of the entries on dict.cc seem to make sense: https://www.dict.cc/?s=verteilten

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, I would translate “Ausdehnung” as expansion, so I think it means that the oceans will cover more area. The phrase “auf der Erde verteilt” means something like “spread across the earth”. It’s a bit superfluous, because I think everyone knows where the oceans are. This would be meaning 3 of “verteilen” in [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verteilen), perhaps slightly figuratively because nobody spread the oceans over the earth, they just happen to be there. But it’s a common phrasing in general.

Answer (score 1):

This *der* isn't a relative pronoun. It introduces a genitive attribute. Let me simplify:

> die Ausdehnung **der** … Ozeane — the expansion **of the** oceans

What may throw you off is that paranthetic word order that is so common in German. It encapsulates all the additional adverbial attributes of a noun phrase between article and noun:

> die Ausdehnung der **auf der Erde verteilten** Ozeane — the expansion of the oceans **spread on Earth**